# Javascript: If (x === 'foo' || 'bar') does not yield a true statement when i use 'bar' . Why?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Any direction on this block of code would be appreciated:

### Variation One:

```js
    var x = 'bar';

    function myFunction(){

        if (x === ('foo' || 'bar')) {
        
           return 'Match';
    
        } else if (x === 'nofoo'){
      
          return 'No Match';

        } else
    
          return 'Blank field';
    }

    console.log(myFunction());
```

The console spits out 'Blank field' when I have the string bar for var x.

The console displays 'Match' when I have var x = 'foo'

### Variation Two:

If I remove the brackets for the following line:

```
if (x === 'foo' || 'bar')
```

Then everything keyed into the var x = '[here]'; becomes a Match.

How does a competent programmer code this so that if x is 'foo' or 'bar' it returns a true statement.

Comment: `('foo' || 'bar')` returns 'foo' `x === ('foo' || 'bar')` checks if x === 'foo'

Comment: As an alternative to posted answers you could also use `Array.includes` like `const arr = ['foo', 'bar']; if (arr.includes(x)) {//do something if 'x' is foo/bar }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (x === 'foo' || x === 'bar')
```

Like that... ;)

Answer (score 1):

That not how `||` is used. You should check if `x` equals `foo` or if `x` equals `bar`;

```
if (x === 'foo' || x === 'bar')
```

In your first code, `x === ('foo' || 'bar')` means: if `x` equals the result of `'foo' || 'bar'` which is `'foo'` because `||` yields the first truthy element. So in this case, the code is equivalent to `if(x === 'foo')`.

In your second code, `x === 'foo' || 'bar'` means: if `x` equals `'foo'` or if `'bar'` is truthy due to the priority of `===` over `||`. Since `'bar'` is truthy, the code is equivalent to `if(true)`.